# Adding a variable to __dirname -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I am trying to add a variable to __dirname because I want to navigate folders depending on that but it doesn't seem to work.

Isn't this the correct way to do so?

```
       var directory = '/some_folder/';

       fs.readdir(__dirname + directory, function(err, files){
            // code
       }
```

To be more precise, I have a folder like so:

```
  A_folder
      some_folder
      some_other_folder
      ..
```

And knowing __dirname is A_folder I want to access the other folders depending on what my "directory" variable is.

Comment: If you're on windows, you might have problems using a forwardslash instead of backslash. Use `path.join` to avoid handling path separators in your code. But otherwise, I believe this should work. Why do you say "it doesn't seem to work"? Are you getting an error? Nothing happens?

Comment: @Sidney, I'm not on windows and nothing happens indeed, it works fine when I write it as `__dirname + '/some_folder/'`, However `__dirname + directory` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `path.join()` to get absolute path. Pass relative path as second argument.

```
var path = require('path');
var directory = path.join(__dirname, './some_folder');

fs.readdir(directory, function(err, files){
     // code
}
```

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't read from that specific folder. In my actual program I have something like `var directory = 'path/to/folder'` which i then change to `path/to/folder/some_folder/` inside a function with path.join but when I call it outside of the function it reads from "folder" even though the path is the correct one: `path/to/folder/some_folder/`